# to check checkbox based on hidden field values

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a table with following structure,in which first TD of each row contains a checkbox.I have a hidden field which  contains comma separated values of second TD of rows whose check box has to be checked(if hidden field contains value of second TD,mark first checkbox checked).Like i have hidden field which contains values "00-0227101-,01-123456789-".Now based on this,i have to mark check box checked.What will be the efficient approach to do this?i have thousands of rows.My approach is to spilt hidden field and then find that value in each TD and then check the checkbox.

```
<tr class="tbs_tr" style="background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery1368711830388="355">
    <TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=0 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368711830388="356"></TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>00-0227101-</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>Medak</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>02/27/2013</TD>
    <TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>02/01/2013</TD>
    </tr>



    <tr class="tbs_tr" style="background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery1368711830388="355">
    <TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=1 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368711830388="358"></TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>01-123456789-</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>2010 Acura CSX 4D Sed</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>Insured Ln, Insured Firstname</TD>
    <TD class=tbs_td>03/05/2013</TD>
    <TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>03/05/2013</TD>
    </tr>


<tr class="tbs_tr" style="background-color: #ffffff;" jQuery1368711830388="355">
<TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=2 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368711830388="360"></TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>01-4444-44401</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>01</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>2001 Toyota Tundra 2 Door Pickup 128" WB 8 Foot Bed</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>Naveen</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>02/11/2013</TD>
<TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>02/10/2013</TD>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged jquery/ajax? Where is your jQuery attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to have a for loop for creating the td elements and while you do that you should have an array with the values (instead of a comma separated hidden value) and check whether the values going to the second td are in the the array you have. If yes set the checkbox to true.

Another way is with jquery:

```
//get the value of the hidden field.
var hidden =  $('input[name=zyx]').val();
//split the string to get an array
var array = hidden.split(',');
//For each tr get the second td's value and see if it's in an array.
$("table tbody tr").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).children('td').slice(0, 2).text();
   if ($.inArray(value, array) > -1)//if it is, check the box in the previous td
   {
     $(this).children('td').slice(0,1).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked",true);
   }
});
```

While the above code is untested and probably won't work straight away, I am sure it will get you on the right track.

Comment: Table is already created, i have to check checkbox based on hidden field value if it matches the 2nd TD value